# Check if a string contains a substring in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

What is the function used to check if a `String` contains a `SubString` in LWC.

In JavaScript, we can use `indexOf`:

```
if (str.indexOf(substr) == -1) {
    // Logic
}
```

What is the equivalent of this in [LWC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LWC is a Javascript framework, and this will work. However, I think you would normally write it as:

```
if (str.indexOf(substr) > -1) {}
```

However, given that LWC is ES6 based, and does not support MS IE 11 or lower, you can actually use:

```
if (str.includes(substr)) {}
```

Which reads a lot cleaner.

Comment: You mean to say `str.includes(substr)` as Javascript doesn't have contains method.

Comment: Ooops!! yes you are right sorry, fixed.